# Turkish char passing from form encoding differs on browser

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8, struts2, character-encoding

I have similar problem discussed in the link. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177914/passing-turkish-char-from-form-to-java-class-with-struts2.

Adding `<Connector ... URIEncoding="UTF-8">` into `server.xml` solves problem.
While using firefox and crome I am not having a problem but same issue occurs using Internet Explorer.

I have checked that page encoding is UTF-8.

What is the difference between internet explorer and others?

Comment: When you say "page encoding" you mean via HTML meta tag, `<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`, or both?

Comment: yes all jsp page has <%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

Comment: Although supposedly that should be sufficient, I'd go ahead and try adding `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` too. I'd bet some versions of IE ignore the response headers and expect the meta tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the proper solution.  First of all I want to mention about my form system.
After clicking an INSERT button pop-up window is opened, in which there is a form as well. and these form data is send to an ACtion via XMLHttpRequest object methods.
 as folowing..

```
     var url = '/MY_WEB/Action.do;

   if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
       req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {


       req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   req.open("GET", url, true);
   req.send(null);
```

Action method type GET causes the problem.
When I have changed from GET to POST method calling, I think stream serialization via UTF encoding works properly with these modification.

```
if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
        http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

    http.open("POST", url, true);

     //Send the proper header information along with the request
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    http.send(params);
```